# file chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation issue

Tags: sharepoint

I run my share point on chrome and launch my Microsoft office online but when i try to insert picture, no file picker dialog pop up in excel or power point.

From developer console, i see "file chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation"

Help is greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: I have also same problem and I can't find any solution after spend few days on it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar situation by just making the input element to be visible (by HTML inspect> unchecking `Display:none`) and then drag the desired file on the `Choose file` button.